# how to publish selected methods in web services c#

Tags: c#, web-services

how to publish selected methods in web services c# i.e. in my web service there are 3 web method present. I want to handle this method manually like on running web service only web method i choose should be run or published only and rest shouldn't be published.
for eg say method1 is selected to run only so on running web service only method1 should be published on localhost and rest methods shouldn't be published.
Please give me some idea.

Comment: If doing manually why not just comment out or remove the WebMethod attribute from those you don't want to "publish" on that occasion?

Comment: The method is chosen programmatically by the user. also there is case of dependency because in my web service dependency is  method2-->method1 and method3-->method1. so  how to do it.It is a scenario of dynamic program slicing

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking cannot be done without doing a republish every time a webservice is called.  This is to put it mildly impractical, and i Highly recommend not doing this method.  Now I think what you are looking for is a way to implement stateless services.  The obvious one here is web api so lets take a look at that.  When you implement a controller the instance of that controller is all that is created for the call making it so for that particular call is the only one that exists on that controller instance, but the other controller methods will still be published, just not accessible from that particular controller.  This allows multiple calls to not interact with each other because the fact that they have separate controller instances